# cannot read from combo box to use as a variable in a sub-routine

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have a variable input come from a combobox. i had thought it would be a simpler task but i am stuck on this and would be grateful for some help.

i am working with pre-packaged code that connects to an API, connects to a server and does stuff. I am customizing it to do a few additional calculations, all of which now work fine, but the variables i use to perform those calcs, inside of one of the sub-routines, are hard coded, and i want to be able to read them in instead using a combobox. i had done this many times using VB6 and VBA, but i am new to vb.net (2010) and even though i have the combobox on my form, every reference to the selected number in the combobox ends up with an empty result

in a simpler application, like the one below, i am able to get the data from the combo box:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim divisor As Integer
    Dim res1 As Integer
    If Int32.TryParse(ComboBox1.Text, divisor) Then
        MsgBox(ComboBox1.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("error" & ComboBox1.Text)
    End If

    res1 = divisor - 9
    MsgBox(res1)

   End Sub
End Class
```

Unfortunately the code i am working with is not cooperating with the code above. without posting all the code, here is the basic structure, maybe this will help you help me figure out where to write the code above so it will grab the value in the combobox where the 'divisor' in the sub13 (see below) will be the number from the combobox instead of it being hard coded

and every reference you see below to the combobox was 'auto-generated'. that is, once i placed the combobox on the form all of that code appeared.

```
Imports X.API

Public Class frmMain
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
   InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Protected Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
End Sub

Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

Friend WithEvents Panel1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()

    Me.ComboBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
    Me.ComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.ComboBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(710, 117)
    Me.ComboBox1.Name = "ComboBox1"
    Me.ComboBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(121, 21)
    Me.ComboBox1.TabIndex = 3
End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Member Variables "
Private mTable As DataTable

#End Region

#Region " Form and Control Events "

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
End Sub

Private Sub s1() 
End Sub

Private Sub s2() 
End Sub

Private Sub s3() 
End Sub

Private Sub s4() 
End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Operations "

Private Sub s5()
End Sub

Private Sub s6()
End Sub

Private Sub s7()
End Sub

Private Sub s8()
End Sub

#End Region

#Region " API Events "

Private Sub s8()
End Sub

Private Sub s9() 
End Sub

Private Sub s10()
End Sub

Private Sub s11()
End Sub

Private Sub s12() 
End Sub

#End Region

Private Sub s13()

    Dim divisor As Integer = 1

    '[this is where i want the divisor to draw from the combobox]

    'so instead of "Dim divisor As Integer = 1"
    i want "Dim divisor As Integer = contents of combobox

End Sub


' i have no idea why this code appears here
Friend WithEvents ComboBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

Private Class Item1
    Public Sub s14()
    End Sub
End Class

Private Class Item2
    Public Sub s15()
    End Sub
End Class

Private Class Item3
    Public Sub s16()
    End Sub
End Class
End Class
```

the sub i am working on is "s13()", but when i try to read from the combobox i get a blank.

exactly where to place the code that works as shown in my first example in the structure i show immediately above is unknown to me. i would have thought it would be much easier to read from a combobox, but i am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the selected item :

```
If Int32.TryParse(ComboBox1.selectedItem, divisor) Then
        MsgBox(ComboBox1.selectedItem)
    Else
        MsgBox("error" & ComboBox1.selectedItem)
    End If
```

Comment: i wish there was an easier way to ask this question. i have the code exactly as you have it written, but the number in the combobox simply does not show up.  at first i get this error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ComboBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.", and your code wont even execute. *then* i stick this line of code right on top of your code " Me.ComboBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()" and i do not get that error message, but even though the number "10" is clearly selected in the combobox, the ComboBox1.SelectedValue is just blank

Comment: -- nothing there, i.e. the data in the combobox is not being read.  something is blocking the read of the combobox, and no doubt it has to do with the rest of the code, which is very dense. but there has to be a simple answer. it must have something to do with where i place the code, using a public variable, class, or something. its realy frustrating me. the thing i thought would be the easiest part of this project has become a little nightmare. thanks for the reply.

Comment: let me try that , a few minutes please

Comment: updated with selectedItem, anyway, it all depends on how your combo is being filled.

Comment: tried selecteditem ... same result; the combobox is filled with a selection from a dropdown list ... thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

Given the names of your functions, it's difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to do.  But you have a couple of options here.  The function itself can access the value from the combo box if it's called while the combo box has a value in it, or the function can require the value as a function argument and whatever calls the function can pass the combo box's value.

For the first, it would look something like this:

```
Private Sub s13()
    Dim divisor as Int32 = 1
    If Int32.TryParse(Me.ComboBox1.Text, divisor) Then
        ' Perform your logic
    Else
        ' The input wasn't a valid integer, maybe show an error?
    End If
End Sub
```

Whereas the second approach might look like this:

```
Private Sub s13(ByVal divisor as Integer)
    ' Perform your logic
End Sub
```

And the code which calls that would need to get the value:

```
Dim divisor as Int32 = 1
If Int32.TryParse(Me.ComboBox1.Text, divisor) Then
    s13(divisor)
Else
    ' The input wasn't a valid integer, maybe show an error?
End If
```

The main thing to note in all of this is that you should use `Int32.TryParse()` to determine if the inputted value in the combo box is actually an integer, and handle the error condition when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

for anybody stuck with the same problem, here is the solution.

the code i had to work with is mammoth, so it would not let me pull in a combobox variable into  any of the subs, esp as this is a multi-threaded prog. i knew, however, the solution had to be simple. and that is always something to keep in mind -- the solution is never that complicated, and you never need as much code as you think.

in this case i went down the path of a *public* variable,

```
Public Shared divisor As Integer
```

i placed this line underneath the very first line

```
Public Class frmMain
```

since there were other drop-down lists on the form that were clearly being drawn from, i went to the code associated with the button that initiated the steps to get the data from the server, just another button_click sub

if *that* sub pulled in the other combo boxes, then it had to grab the data in the one i wanted. all i did then was add this line of code to that button_click sub

```
divisor = ComboBox1.Text
```

since divisor is now a public variable, what was recorded in the button_click sub easily passes to another private sub that runs other routines. so anywhere in the code i want to use the variable 'divisor' all i have to do is mention it :)

```
 if divisor > 0 then
 'do something
 end if
```